# package com.mongodb.client does not exist

Tags: java, mongodb

I am getting error in eclipse console while  building application

> package com.mongodb.client does not exist.

I am importing two packages :

```
import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;
import org.bson.Document;
```

Comment: Show your build path and dependencies. Package not found means library is missing.

Answer (score -1):

Download the jar files of the packages and add it to the build path of your project.

If you are using maven, add the dependency in pom.xml

Comment: have you installed jvm ? If yes, make sure its added to your environment variable(windows) or class path (unix)

Comment: You should describe how to do the thing you're suggesting, not just say "DO THIS".